# How to destructing two variables that are nested in an object in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

Let's say I have obj like

```
const user = {
 id: 339,
 name: 'Fred',
 age: 42,
 education: {
   getDegree: () => {} //function
 }
};
const {education: {getDegree}} = user;
```

I often have a use case that needs to get both education and degree as parameter from user obj.

I only know how to destruct getDegree from obj, what to do to get the education variable as well?

something to do the same thing, but I believe there is a better way to do this?

```
const {education: {getDegree}} = user;
const {education} = user;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just list `education` in the destructure as well:

```js
const user = {
 id: 339,
 name: 'Fred',
 age: 42,
 education: {
   foo: "bar"
 }
};
const {education, education: {foo}} = user;

console.log(education);
console.log(foo);
```